# query in Conditional Statements in Python

Tags: python

I am newbie to Python and programming environment .Now I am studying python via online .I Landed up a small trouble while studying If Statements . The IF statement is currently interpreting while the ELSE statement is written it displays me a syntax error attached Screen Shot will make my problem understandble more clearly:[image]

not only ELSE statement even ELIF statement also displays a syntax error.

Comment: Spacing is the main thing in Python. you need to intend your code properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spacing, else should be under if

```
if (x%2 == 0):
    print "x is even"
else:
    print "x is odd"
```

Answer (score 3):

the if and else need to be indented the same amount

for example

```
x = 5
if 8 > x:
    print "8 is greater than x"
else:
```

same goes for elif

```
x = 5
if 8 > x:
    print "8 is greater than x"
elif 8 < x:
    print "8 is less than x"
else:
```

Comment: It follows indentations for code blocks.In other languages we have '{}' for code blocks.

Comment: @codehorse I edited your post to actually fix the indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation is everything in python. By

```
if x%2==0:
    print "even"
    else:
    ^^^
```

You mean to say that the else statement also comes under the if block, as it is one block of indent after the `if` statement. This throws an error as there is no `if` for the else that you have given. Now lets come to the correct way:

```
if x%2==0:
    print "even"
else:
    print "odd"
```

Here, since if and else are in the same indent, the else is corresponding to the if, and the else is executed if the if condition fails.